# How add Flyway dependency and build native image Quarkus java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFileFilter

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, flyway, quarkus

I'm building an app using quarkus, kotlin and flyway.
Everything works fine with the JVM execution, but it fails when we try to build a native image.
After some debugging I found that the way Quarkus builds the native image is trying to load some dependencies from Flyway that we are not using like jboss-vfs or the Android SDK.

This is the output from the `mvn package -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true` command:

[image]

The inner exception message is

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFileFilter

What's the "right way" to add Flyway as a dependency and being able to compile a native image without adding all the unused/optional dependencies?

Comment: As far as I know flyway has never been tested with Quarkus and native execution. Your best bet would be to ask the Quarkus mailing list for some pointers on the problem

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I created a simple project to test this issue https://github.com/cristhiank/quarkus-flyway-bug.git

Comment: Thanks for moving this forward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus supports Flyway without issues when executing in JVM mode, so you can use it as always.

Quarkus native applications with Flyway are not supported yet. 
Some work to support it is in progress here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1575